# What's the new name of BaseEndpointCoprocessor in HBASE 0.96

Tags: hbase

I'm checking the documents about the endpoint coprocessor, and I found that the CoprocessorProtocol is already renamed as "CoprocessorService".

- See HBASE-6485: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6895
  Remove CoprocessorProtocol support and implementations

  Dynamic endpoints must now be refactored to use CoprocessorService instead of CoprocessorProtocol. See the coprocessor package info javadoc for example. Study unit tests for examples where we migrate for old style to new. Write the mailing list if you need help because a few fellas have volunteered to help those who need to migrate.

But I can't find any information about the "BaseEndpointCoprocessor", I try to use it in my endpoint class but seems it is also removed and renamed (?)

Is there anyone know where can I find the related information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing in 0.96 is [BaseRowProcessorEndpoint](http://search-hadoop.com/jd/hbase/hbase-server/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/BaseRowProcessorEndpoint.html)